# Mixing multiple traits in Scala

Tags: scala, mixins, traits

*Quick note: Examples from the tutorial *[Scala for Java Refugees Part 5: Traits and Types](https://web.archive.org/web/20170423024917/http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-5)*.*

Suppose I have the traits Student, Worker, Underpaid, and Young.

How could I declare a class (**not instance**), CollegeStudent, with all these traits?

*Note:* I am aware of the simplests cases, such as CollegeStudent with one or two Traits:

```
class CollegeStudent extends Student with Worker
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It is easy, when declaring a class you just use the "with" keyword as often as you want

```
class CollegeStudent extends Student with Worker with Underpaid with Young
```

the order of the traits can be important if a trait is changing the behavior of the class, it all depends on traits you are using.

Also if you don't want to have a class which always uses the same traits you can use them later:

```
class CollegeStudent extends Student
new CollegeStudent with Worker with Underpaid with NotSoYoungAnymore
```

Comment: Changing the behavior means to call a trait methods which is implemented and having the same name in multiple traits. So based upon the order of trait it will call that method.

Answer (score 19):

I think that it is very important to explain not only the syntax, but **also which role does the ordering of the traits play**. I found the explanation in Jason Swartz's [Learning Scala](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030287.do) (page 177) quite enlightning.

- A Scala class can extend multiple traits at once, but JVM classes can extend only one parent class. The Scala compiler solves this by creating "*copies of each trait to form a tall, single-column hierarchy of the
  class and traits*", a process known as **linearization**.
- In this context, extending multiple traits with identical field names would fail to compile, exactly the same "*as if you were extending a class and providing your own version of a method but failed to add an override keyword*".

And since it determines the shape of the inheritance tree, the linearization order is indeed one very important question to regard. As an example, `class D extends A with B with C` (where A is a class and B
and C are traits) would become `class D extends C extends B extends A`. The following few lines, also from the book, illustrate that perfectly:

```
trait Base { override def toString = "Base" }
class A extends Base { override def toString = "A->" + super.toString }
trait B extends Base { override def toString = "B->" + super.toString }
trait C extends Base { override def toString = "C->" + super.toString }
class D extends A with B with C { override def toString = "D->" + super.toString }
```

A call to `new D()` would have the REPL print the following:

```
 D->C->B->A->Base
```

Which perfectly reflects the structure of the linearized inheritance graph.