# Why is override sometimes required for an abstract method?

Tags: scala

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182368/stack-modification-traits-in-scala-not-working), the following code compiles OK

```
trait Logger {
  def log(msg: String): Unit
}

trait LoggerA extends Logger {
  def log(msg: String) = ???
}

trait LoggerB extends Logger {
  override def log(msg: String) = ???
}

class Logged1 extends LoggerA 
class Logged2 extends LoggerB
class Logged3 extends LoggerA with LoggerB
```

The `override` is not required in `LoggerA`  because there is no concrete implementation of `log` in `Logger`.

However if I remove the `override` from `LoggerB` it no longer compiles:

```
class Logged3 inherits conflicting members:
  def log(msg: String): Nothing (defined in trait LoggerA) and
  def log(msg: String): Nothing (defined in trait LoggerB)
  (note: this can be resolved by declaring an `override` in class Logged3.)
```

Why is `override` required in this [specific case](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IAD8lf5yST6q3s0QTrEWQA)? Does specifying `override` change the method or the class in some way?

Comment: It seems if we have 2 traits having same override methods from base trait, and if we mixin those 2 trait  the right most trait's overridden method will be executed. And if the right most trait overridden method does not use override key word that causes error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is specified by [SLS 5.1.4 Overriding](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#overriding)

> If M′ is not an abstract member, then M must be labeled `override`.
> ... or both M and M′ override a third member M'' which is defined in a
> base class of both the classes containing M and M'.

Also in section [5.1.3 Class Members](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-members) there is a similar use of override to OP

```
trait A { def f: Int }
trait B extends A { def f: Int = 1 ; def g: Int = 2 ; def h: Int = 3 }
trait C extends A { override def f: Int = 4 ; def g: Int }
trait D extends B with C { def h: Int }
```

thus at least it does seem a specified behaviour.

Based on [fr_andres' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958910/5205022) and [Learning Scala, Chapter 9. Objects, Case Classes, and Traits](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/ch09.html#traits_section)

> a class extending class A and traits B and C is actually extending one
> class, which extends another class, which extends another class, when
> compiled to the .class binary file.

which due to linearization implies effectively

```
LoggerA (has concrete log)
  ^
  |
LoggerB (also has concrete log)
  ^
  |
Logged3
```

and `override` is necessary when overriding a concrete implementation.

Comment: Yeah, OK, I guess that makes sense. `LoggerA` inserts itself between `LoggerB` and `Logger` so `override` is now required in `LoggerB`. I had missed this particular effect of linearization.